# HSQLDB Resultset - how to get HSQLDB return space without quotes as space and not null?

Tags: null, hsqldb, resultset, space

I am using HSQLDB to link existing text files, fire SQL upon it to retrieve data in resultset.
Problem is if text file has data as space, HSQL DB Resultset returns null for those.
For ex: text file row:

> data1|data2|| |data3

I am expecting Resultset as

> data1,data2,null, ,data3

The HSQLDB doc guid/Chpt5 states that: "Empty fields are treated as NULL. These are fields where there is nothing or just spaces between the separators."
Is there a way to change this default behaviour? treat no space between seperators as Null and space between seperators as space?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [HSQLDB documentation](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch06.html), "Quoted empty strings are treated as empty strings.". In your case, are you able to modify the existing text files? If so, you could replace all instances of one or more spaces between two seperators using a regular expression (ex: `\|\s+\|`) with the quoted equivalent:

```
data1|data2|| |data3
```

would become

```
data1|data2||" "|data3
```

This should allow HSQLDB to pick up those field values instead of setting them to null.

Comment: Thanks krautmeyer! There is another problem there.. there are some data in text file which are included in quotes, esp the ones whilch might containg data seperators, Ex: Data1| Data2|"Da|ta3"|. So in order to read these values as it is, I am using quoted = fasle property. so If I do replace space character by " ", it reads space as " ".

Comment: That does make it more complicated - can you modify the source files in two passes? First, replace each double quote with the escaped version (`""`). Then, do the pass to replace spaces with the quoted equivalent as before. If HSQLDB doesn't like that, you'll have to clean up your data properly and quote any fields that contain a double-quote character.